# Mosfet Motor Drive amplifying duty cycle of PWM

Tags: pwm, dc-motor

I am receiving PWM signal at 7.8V from a given controller, with which we need to control the speed of a DC motor at 18 V. I implemented the following circuit for this.
[image]
However, the output to motor signal (blue) is not following the original PWM (yellow)  and duty cycle is increased by 50%. What could be the culprit. I dont think it is the awkward taper off on the downleg of the input signal [image].

What could be a remedy?

---

How about this solution?

[How to reduce MOSFET turn-off delay](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/74466/11683)

Comment: Tyr to reduce 10k resistor to 1k or more. Or add a voltage follower https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry2GB.png

Comment: What is the driver for the "awkward signal"?  That is your problem.  The NPN is an inverting current sink with a current gain of hFE and it's output is not shown. The result can work if there is a fast turn off of the base current., such as with 10K to gnd on PWM input.   The FET bias looks ok.  Also show cable layout

Comment: You probably want to use a commercial mosfet driver instead of building one yourself. A mosfet driver will take a logical input signal (you may have to reduce the 7.8V to 5V), and will produce a high current output sufficient to charge the mosfet's gate capacitance.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist The source is another micro-controller with proprietary software/hardware. We are constrained to use it.

Comment: @C_Elegans can you recommend a good diver? What do you think about IRF9540?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments/suggestions provided here, we found the solution. We modeled the circuit in Proteus and were able to recreate the output signal.
[image: Proteus recreation of Original Circuit]
Then, as suggested by @G36 the 10k ohm resistor was reduced to 820 ohm, and few minor modifications.
[image: Modified Circuit]
Simulation environment predicted better results:
[image: Simulated output of modified circuit]
On oscilloscope too results were verified as true to form.
[image: Actual output of modified circuit]

Thanks to all contributors!