# driving high-side N-channel MOSFETs in H-Bridge

Tags: mosfet, pwm

What is the most efficient / best way to make an H-bridge? I want low power loss but also fast switching time since I will using PWM. I have considered using 2 P-channel and 2 N-channel MOSFETs to make this. But, I realized that P-channel devices have a much higher channel resistance causing more power loss.

So, I was considering using 4 N-channel MOSFETs but the problem lies with the gate voltage. My power source will be approximately 15V and I am going to be using a arduino/atmega for PWM signal (5V). So, I am wondering what is the best way to amplify this gate voltage so that the high side N-channel MOSFETs turn on while also giving me a rapid switch time. Or, am I digging a hole for myself and should just stick with a P-channel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [driving low side of a mosfet bridge with 3.3V](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56140/driving-low-side-of-a-mosfet-bridge-with-3-3v)

Comment: There are really at least three problems here, each complex enough to merit separate questions: 1) driving MOSFETs in parallel, 2) using N-channel MOSFETs for the high side, and 3) designing a proper gate driver to switch MOSFETs quickly. If the general answers already here don't address your question, I'd suggest you edit or ask a new one to be more specific.

Comment: How much current? What sort of switching speeds are you talking about? Have you considered an integrated solution (IC)?

Comment: 1) What do you mean by low power loss? 2) When saying that you'll drive it by PWM, do you mean that you'll employ LPF to integrate the PWM, or each high phase of PWM should open the MOSFETs?

Comment: I'm not being sarcastic, it seems from your wording you don't know these exist.  [Gate Driver IC's](http://www.irf.com/product-info/hvic/)

Comment: Take a look at OSMC (Open Source Motor Controller) website, that will give example circuits (at least for motor control) but you need to give more info for a more exact answer, ref previous comments.

Comment: See my answer to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78943/how-can-i-switch-a-high-side-transistor-from-logic-referenced-to-ground/78979#78979

Comment: @Matt Anderson I think if you are not being sarcastic you are at least not helping so much. Gate driver ICs are not a standart, and have many pros and cons, as having so much types of implementation too. For a infinity on-time of the high-side switch, a boot-strap gate drive IC, will not work (only if using a isolated supply for the high side, so no bootstrap will be used).

Answer (score 3):

I pressume that by power loss, you refering to the power dissipation on the transistors.

So in this case, P-channel MOSFETs have high on-resistence, so its common for high current
applications to use N-channel at the top of the bridge too.

To drive the top transistors, you have some options. Some of then:

- Pulse-transformers
- Gate-drive IC's that can be of different topology's like boot-strapping.
- Isolated power supply with level-shifter
- Isolated power supply with Opto-isolators

All with their characteristics.

Some good app-note
http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slup169/slup169.pdf

Answer (score 1):

On my point of view, you could select a pre-driver to drive the H-bridge. As I know, Infineon has a lot of ICs to solve your problem. And if you want to design a low power loss circuits, you'd better forcus on your Mosfet's Rdson and Qg. P-channel is not recommended. Because its high Rdson.